# How to create/update nested Serializers with Filefields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a python 3.6 + django 1.10 + djangorestframework 3.6.4 project.
I have 2 Model classes called Report and ReportFile. I want to create the CRUD operations to get, post and put those files together with a report.
1 Report has a type (which doesn't really matter here) and can have many ReportFiles that the user should be able to upload.
The modelclasses look like this:

```
class Report(CreationModificationMixin):
    report_type = models.ForeignKey(ReportType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, 
                  null=True, related_name='issues',
                                    verbose_name='Report', editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class ReportFile(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='files')
    uploaded_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='uploads',
                                    null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_report_to, max_length=500)
```

and the serializer class:

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    files = ReportFileSerializer(many=True)
    formats = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'report_type', 'files')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        rfs_data = validated_data.pop('files')
        rf = Report.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for rf_data in rfs_data:
            ReportFile.objects.create(Report=rf, **rf_data)
        return rf
```

and the ViewSet:

```
class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer
    queryset = Report.objects.all().prefetch_related('report_type')
```

But I cannot manage to upload the files correctly. Because first I cannot manage to upload that correctly with Postman and I somehow also doubt that this is the correct way to go. Can somebody hint me how I should do this?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I would recommend to get base64encode values and accept in database with text input, and while displaying it either create hard file of it and save OR you can directly put into image tag.

Comment: So you mean I should send in the POST/PUT of the Rest Client a base64 encoded value representing the file directly to the server and creating the file out of that?

Comment: yes. that's is the only option while interacting with REST API and client.

Comment: Hm since I need to do that on server side anyway for indexing them for elastic search it might actually be a good idea. The only downsides are an overhead for the upload because b64 is more data and the client has to convert it to b64 I guess.

Comment: yes, but methods are easily available.